# What is the expectation operator of the False Discovery Rate taken under?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, false-discovery-rate

The False Discovery Rate is usually defined as:

$$
FDR = E(Q)
$$

where $Q$ is the proportion of false discoveries. I am wondering what this expectation is under. Is it a generic sample expectation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could call it a "generic sample expectation" yes. It is the mean proportion of all false discoveries over an infinite number of repetitions of your experiment and associated hypothesis tests.